# WPF MouseDown bubbling event doesn't bubble when clicking left button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have such XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewTestingWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseDown="Control_MouseDown">
            <Button x:Name="button1" Width="80" Height="50" MouseDown="Control_MouseDown" Margin="10" >
                <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Red" MouseDown="Control_MouseDown" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And metod "Control_MouseDown()":

```
private void Control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "sender: " + sender.ToString() + "\n";
            textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text + "source: " + e.Source.ToString() + "\n\n";
        }
```

Everything goes good when I click on red ellipse using right button or wheel, I get such expected result:

[image: pic 1]

But when I use left button event doesn't bubble and I get only this:

[image: pic 2]

Why do everything goes this way?

**UPD**
Frenchy says that propably Click event "eats" MouseDown is it possible to avoid such behavior?

Comment: i think Click event eat up the MouseDown, try PreviewMouseDown event which is a tunnelling event

Answer (score 1):

when i use PreviewMouseDown all seems ok

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseDown="Control_MouseDown">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Width="80" Height="50" PreviewMouseDown="Control_MouseDown" Margin="10" >
            <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Red" PreviewMouseDown="Control_MouseDown" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: But if I will need exactly bubbling event?

Comment: you just Check for e.OriginalSource to see which element is actual original source. On the ellipse dont need to add control. I dont see other solution for your problem